# Using Highcharts on Node JS

Tags: json, node.js, highcharts

I'm trying to display a JSON object as a chart. I am using NodeJS. And I installed Highcharts package. I went through [https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts](http://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts) to add it to my Server.js file. But when I run it, I'm getting the following error:

```
/scratch/sivasubr/node-project/node_modules/highcharts/modules/exporting.js:9
(function(f){typeof module==="object"&&module.exports?module.exports=f:f(Highcharts)})(function(f){var s=f.win,j=s.document,B=f.Chart,u=f.addEvent,C=f.removeEvent,D=f.fireEvent,r=f.createElement,t=f.discardElement,w=f.css,l=f.merge,m=f.each,q=f.extend,F=f.splat,G=Math.max,H=f.isTouchDevice,I=f.Renderer.prototype.symbols,z=f.getOptions(),A;q(z.lang,{printChart:"Print chart",downloadPNG:"Download PNG image",downloadJPEG:"Download JPEG image",downloadPDF:"Download PDF document",downloadSVG:"Download SVG vector image",
                                                                                                              ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined
at /scratch/sivasubr/node-project/node_modules/highcharts/modules/exporting.js:9:115
```

1. Can someone tell me how to resolve this?
2. Is there a better way to display a JSON object as a graph on Node JS?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? NodeJS is a platform for creating server code, while Highcharts is more frontend minded.

Comment: How have you installed Highcharts and loaded it in your code? Here's official instructions: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/install-from-npm